# Click Reopen and I get a nondescript message

Tags: discussion, feature-request, vote-to-reopen, popups

I was just testing out the reopen functionality on a question which a Mod deleted (so I know I cannot reopen it) ([How can I upload file from internet (i have file url) using ajaxupload plugin? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7431961/561731)).

When I clicked on reopen I got the confirmation box as usual:

[image]

After I clicked ok, this showed on the page:

[image]

Voted?

I understand that it is a `VOTE`, a vote to reopen a question (which I know cannot be reopened because it is deleted)

**BUT**  I am suggesting better wording:

> This post has been deleted. Deleted posts cannot be reopened

The word reopened describes what I was trying to do.  I was *not* trying to vote on the question, I was trying to *reopen* it.

Comment: *I understand that it is a VOTE* Well then.

Comment: @Shog9 lol i know that :-P

Comment: hmm the tooltip for "undelete" reads *vote to restore this post* but wait... I thought I couldn't vote on deleted posts

Comment: @Conrad -- I just added the confirmation box for reopen -- it mentions **nothing** about about voting. Whereas the `undelete` confirmation does.